# Azure + Bitbucker Error on WebSocket

Tags: azure, bitbucket, setup-deployment, azure-deployment

I'm trying to configure Bitbucket as Deployment source for a Web App.

This App is inside a Application Service Environment v2 that is "blocked" from the outside so I can't deploy from Visual Studio.

When I try to connect bitbucket I get this error:

```
Failed to set up deployment source for web app almondstech, using Bitbucket. {"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Bitbucket AddWebHook: (400) BadRequest.
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.BitbucketV2Proxy.d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
t System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.BitbucketV2SiteRepositoryProvider.d__6.MoveNext()
'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OAuthException: Bitbucket AddWebHook: (400) BadRequest. at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.BitbucketV2Proxy.d__41.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at
```

I already tried to remove / add again the App on Bitbucket and with several browsers, always with the same result.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you expect, the Bitbucket webhook needs your SCM endpoint to be reachable publicly.